# Open street Map api android

Tags: android, zooming, openstreetmap, continuous

I tried to find OSM api for my android app, but projects such as osmdroid have only descret zoom. But my application must have smooth zoom (like in google maps, mapsme)

Answer (score 0):

This will require vector [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) instead of raster tiles. Take a look at the [list of OSM vector tile libraries for Android](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles#Android) and projects such as mapsforge or Mapbox GL.